# Htaccess rewrite condicion url with dash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble to make this htaccess work

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([temp|ox|cond|new-url]+)/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ graph.php?grap=$1&time=$2 [NC,L]
```

Before adding `new-url` condition to the rewrite condition it was working OK

I also tried to put `new\-url` and `new/-url` but doesn't work either

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few errors in your file.

First, `([temp|ox|cond|new-url]+)` is the same as `([cdelmnoprtuwx|-]+)`. Here you're searching for **characters**, not **words**. If I understand, you're looking for urls starting by either `/temp/`, `/ox/`, `/cond/` or `new-url`. So I would use this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(temp|ox|cond|new-url)/
```

Second, when you match `new-url`, there's a dash. But your next rule doesn't accept any dash! Change for this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)$ graph.php?grap=$1&time=$2 [NC,L]
```

Notes:

- I used `[a-z]` instead of `[A-Za-z]` as your rule doesn't take case in account (`[NC]`)
- I added the dash at the end of the character range: `[a-z-]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the - inside character class.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([temp|ox|cond|new\-url]+)/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ graph.php?grap=$1&time=$2 [NC,L]
```

If that doesnt solve the issue, you can use a simple pattern :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(temp|ox|cond|new-url)/?
```